# TSQL: running exec after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to convert old data from multiple tables. I only just found out now, after writing the stored procedure to do this for one table, that it needs to also handle data from a couple other tables. This means that my procedure needs to be changed to properly handle this. I would like to do this dynamically, while keeping away from performance hits. I learned about using exec sp_executesql @SQLStatement to avoid performance issues with dynamic SQL.

However, if I write the below, I get no results:

```
SET @SQLStatement = 'select CONVERT(XML, ' + @ConvColumn + ') ' + @AdditionalColumns + ' from ' + @ConvTable
INSERT INTO @TempDataConv
exec sp_executesql @SQLStatement
```

Yet, if I write it explicitly defining the table and columns, this works just fine:

```
INSERT INTO @TempDataConv
SELECT
    DecPageID,
    PolicyID,
    PolicyNumber,
    CONVERT(XML, DecInfo),
    null
FROM [InternalPortal].[dbo].Decpages
```

What might be going on? As no results are returned, I am unsure how to figure out the problem. I assume that perhaps I cannot do the below. Is that true? Should I simply write this out in if blocks for the different tables?

```
 INSERT INTO @TempDataConv
exec sp_executesql @SQLStatement
```

Comment: You have a major injection issue there before anything. I would fix that first. Also, I would, personally, include the `INSERT` inside the dynamic SQL, not perform an `INSERT INTO ... EXEC ...`.

Comment: Ah yep. Thank you for the reminder and the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you would get more similar performance if you perform the `INSERT` inside the dynamic statement, not using an `INSERT INTO...EXEC...`. This would result in something like this:

```
DECLARE @ConvColumn sysname,
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @AdditionalColumns table (Position int,ColumnName sysname);

SET @ConvColumn = N'DecInfo';

INSERT INTO @AdditionalColumns
VALUES(1,N'DecPageID'),
      (2,N'PolicyID'),
      (3,N'PolicyNumber');

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable ({ColumnsList})' + @CRLF +
           N'SELECT CONVERT(xml, ' + QUOTENAME(@ConvColumn) + N'),' + @CRLF +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'       ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                  FROM @AdditionalColumns
                  ORDER BY Position ASC
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + @CRLF +
          N'FROM [InternalPortal].[dbo].Decpages;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

One caveat, you won't be able to use a table variable to `INSERT` into, however, you could create a temporary table, outside the scope of the dynamic statement, and `INSERT` into that.

Notice, as well, that I make this secure by the use of `QUOTENAME`. This is why I use a table variable to store the names of the columns, as you would never be able to achieve that with a delimited list (and that would *really* leave the injection gates wide open). You'll also need to replace `{ColumnsList}` with the actual columns to be inserted into.

Comment: Thank you. How does the usage of QUOTENAME prevent SQL injection? Also, I can simply build the column list in the stored proc based on the received table value..

Comment: `QUOTENAME` safely quotes the injected value, @Noone , meaning someone can't use it to inject. Rather than repeating myself, here's an article where I expand on it on an article I wrote a couple years ago: [Why QUOTENAME is important](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-quotename-is-important)

Comment: Considering this about performance what does "not solve the problem" mean? At least elaborate on your comment. It certainly, however, solves the injection issues.

Comment: This is about a programmatic solution, not performance. That is important, however I want something that actually works to solve my stated issue...

Comment: The only problem you describe is in regards to performance in your question, @Noone .If this isn't about performance, then your question isn't telling us what the *real* question is.

Comment: Wrong. You completely ignored the fact that the code must actually work, which it does not. Check your own code....

Comment: You say it "doesn't work" @Noone , however, you've given me no sample data to test it with and don't tell me what "doesn't work" means. I'll be *more* than happy to show you it working if you provide sample data and tell me what "does not work" means (i.e. the error). Have you also looked at your "friend" to help you debug it? You are asking for help, for *free* from the users here; there is no need to be so obnoxious...

Comment: This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=591522c0559d0ec3e0b3b0da60ce484b), however, provides perfectly valid SQL, apart from the part I told you you need to replace, telling me your implementation is incorrect, not my SQL.